# How to split a string with two continuous spaces

Tags: c#, string, split, space

I have a string that consists of continuous spaces like

```
a(double space)b c d (Double space) e f g h (double space) i
```

split like

```
a
b c d
e f g h
i
```

at present i am trying like this

```
   Regex r = new Regex(" +");
        string[] splitString = r.Split(strt);
```

Comment: did you try Split("  ") ?

Comment: @bobek That wouldn't work

Comment: .Split("Doublespace")?

Comment: @sgud That wouldn't work (or even compile) either.

Comment: And of the code that you're trying, what is the result?  Why isn't it working?  What *is* happening?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx):

```
var items = theString.Split(new[] {"  "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
string s = "a  b c d  e f g h  i";
var test = s.Split(new String[] { "  " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Console.WriteLine(test[0]); // a
Console.WriteLine(test[1]); // b c d
Console.WriteLine(test[2]); // e f g h
Console.WriteLine(test[3]); // i
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/6Fpoqh)

Another way would be to use Regular Expressions, which would allow you to split on *any* whitespace over two characters:

```
string s = "a      b c d   e f g h      \t\t i";
var test = Regex.Split(s, @"\s{2,}");

Console.WriteLine(test[0]); // a
Console.WriteLine(test[1]); // b c d
Console.WriteLine(test[2]); // e f g h
Console.WriteLine(test[3]); // i
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/lX4Upa)

Comment: Thanks for the regex example.
I was having issues with split to split up telephone number into it code and number, by single space. Data came form API, JSON. Split did not want to work, and somehow read the single space as double. 
i used regex and it worked 

string[] arr = Regex.Split(numbers, @"\s{1,}");

Not sure why. number was "+381 112085917". did this in response write just to check before split. 
When i did string[] arr = "+381 112085917".Split(' '); it worked. Just when using  string[] arr = numbers.Split(' '); it would end up with 3 array number and arr[1] being empty

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) method.

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this string
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string array. A
>   parameter specifies whether to return empty array elements.

```
string s = "a  b c d  e f g h  i";
var array = s.Split(new string[] {"  "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var element in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine (element);
}
```

Output will be;

```
a
b c d
e f g h
i
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/hLkk3J)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression is an elegant solution

```
string[] match = Regex.Split("a  b c d  e f g h  i", @"/\s{2,}/",  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: How does this split the string?

Comment: I know how `Regex.Match` works.  I don't think it achieves what the OP is asking.  `-1` from me.